# German for nickname?

Tags: word-choice

A German-speaking friend of mine referred to another person, Madeline, by the nickname "Maddie." Except that she used the term "cozy name."

Google translate gives me "Spitzname," or more likely "sobriquet," for nickname. Are these good translations? I also get "gemütlich" for cozy, but I don't think there is anything like "gemütlichname."

Is there a better German usage for "nickname," or as my friend put it, "cozy name?"

Comment: "Gemütlichname" sounds like "Dr. Merkwürdigliebe". (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dr._Strangelove)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The others are right:

What you're looking for is Spitzname.

It's worth differentiating the other suggestions, though:

- **Kosename** -- This is a "term of endearment" (and you're right: this is very likely the original of the botched "cozy name". The "Kose-" part is related to "liebkosen" and evokes the mental image of being (physically) affectionate to this person.)
- **Neckname**, **Scherzname**, **Spottname** -- These are terms for negative or teasing nicknames, to a larger or lesser degree. However, since this is also covered by "Spitzname", and the're *very* uncommon, I wouldn't recommend using them (even though Duden lists them).
- **Sobriquet** -- This is *not* a German word - don't trust Google translate :)

Answer (score 10):

The term *[Sobriquet](http://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/Sobriquet)* will not be understood by most native German speakers.

There's a simple rule that you can follow to figure out which word you can use in German:

Use *[Kosename](http://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/Kosename)* for family or partner, i.e. people that are very close to you:

> Ich gebe meiner Frau Kosenamen.

Use *[Nickname](http://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/Nickname)* when talking about one's online name:

> Wie ist dein Nickname?

And [Spitzname](http://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/Spitzname) in any other situation.

Comment: Very true concerning the usage of *Nickname* in German - one might say that the meaning of *Nickname* in German is closer to that of *Benutzername* (user name) than to that of *Spitzname*.

Answer (score 3):

[Dict.cc](http://www.dict.cc) lists these as [possible translations](http://www.dict.cc/?s=nickname):

- Spitzname
- Kosename
- Neckname
- Scherzname
- Spottname

The [German Wikipedia](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spitzname) has `Spitzname` as the equivalent of `nickname`.

In my opinion, `Spitzname` is the best translation for `nickname`.

[`Kosename`](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kosename) is mostly used for a person for which the speaker feels affection.

---

BTW: I have never heard `cozy name` before.

Comment: "Kosename is mostly used for a person for which the speaker feels affection." That's what I needed to know. But it does sound like "cozy name." I think that this was her (mis)"translation" of Kosename.

Comment: I think that *nickname* is used in a slightly more general sense then *Spitzname*, and that a *Spitzname* is often taunting or at least humorous. I think (but am not sure of it, because that would require better knowledge of English than I have) that this does not have to be the case for a *nickname*.  Also, it is very much possible that the usage of *Spitzname* is changing.

Comment: @TomAu, thanks to Wikipedia you can tell her that she meant a term of endearment ;)

Comment: @CarstenSchultz "Spitzname" need not be humorous. My own nick at stackexchange is a "Spitzname" I got during high school. It's not humorous at all.

Comment: Then maybe @Toscho is not a Spitzname ;)  As I said, the meaning may be shifting, but the original meaning is narrower, see the entries in all three dictionaries at http://woerterbuchnetz.de or even the 1986 edition of Wahrig.

Answer (score 2):

I am from Germany:

> - Spitzname

That's exactly what you are looking for. Maddie is a *Spitzname* for Madeline. You only call the person by their *Spitzname* when you are a good friend of the person.  A *Spitzname* can be without any relation to the name. For example Madelines *Spitzname* can as well be *whateveryouwant*.

*Opa* for example is a *Kosename* for *Großvater*. Like papa for father.

> - Neckname
> - Scherzname
> - Spottname

I never used any of these and I never heard someone using them.

Answer (score -3):

May I offer **Rufname** as another alternative to **Spitzname**. I've heard it used in the context and it makes sense given the duality [defined by Duden](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Rufname)

> 1. Vorname einer Person, mit dem sie angeredet wird (im Unterschied zu weiteren Vornamen)
> 2. (besonders Funkwesen) Kennung

However, **Spitzname** would certainly be the one used in *most* cases for the context you gave.

**Rufname** literally translates to "calling name" (or "name someone is called by") and I have heard it used to refer to the nickname rather than simply any forename. In fact I have heard it in both cases. However, there are a lot of regionalisms in German, so this may be a local thing. Just wanted to give it for completeness.

Comment: **Rufname is definitely not an alternative to Spitzname!** If you have more than one given name (e.g Magaretha Maria Schmidt), the "Rufname" is the one that is used to call you in everyday life. It can be any of the given names and it is not automatically the first name in the order of the given names. In formulas the Rufname is often underlined.

Comment: @Iris: hab ich selbst geschrieben. Ich bleib dabei, denn ich habe es exakt so schon von anderen benutzt gehört. Ob das nun anderen gefällt oder nicht, ist für mich nachrangig. Auch als Muttersprachler lerne ich hin und wieder neue Fakten zu meiner Muttersprache und halte mich nicht für die letzte Instanz in Sprachfragen.